# d3 (or dc.js) scatter plot with data table

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, dc.js

I have a csv file composed of 100K records and for each row I have x, y and z attributes.

I want to show a scatterplot where I plot every record with respect to x and y values. When brushed, below the scatter plot - I'd like to display the selected records: x, y and z values.

The display of records can be done with dc.js dataTable. I think I can also get the scatter plot by modifying dc.js bubble chart. However, as far as I looked that doesn't have brushing event implemented. I wonder if anyone has any tips or advice regarding to a pure d3 implementation. Please note that the csv file is about 20mb if that matters at all.

Note: I've seen [this](http://static.cybercommons.org/js/d3/examples/brush/brush.html) scatterplot implementation (http://static.cybercommons.org/js/d3/examples/brush/brush.html) however I am worried on its limitations with a large dataset.

Comment: Oddly, dc.js [also has a scatter plot](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.scatterPlot) which does support brushing. To scale to a huge number of points, you might be better off with a canvas implementation like Chart.js but I don't know if anyone has published crossfilter integration for it.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I'll take a look at Chart.js.

Comment: You should also try the dc.js one but it will probably get bogged down. I know people you can bug if you need help with the Chart.js-crossfilter integration, just email me. :)